# WF 4.0 correlate separate services

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have an application that has a designer component that creates WF workflow services. These services are than saved as .xamlx files in a directory and with relevant changes to web.config.None of the service instances are persisted.

Many of these services might call each other, so I would like to correlate the calls for appfabric monitoring and other purposes. 
From what i have read, one can correlate receive activities,but they all have to share an instance, so they have to be part of same service.

Is it possible to correlate completely separate services ? I can configure it in a way that they all use context enabled bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Correlation is all about getting multiple messages into the same workflow instance.

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring purposes if you enable end-to-end monitoring it will add an activity ID to your messages that you can use to correlate all related events regardless of which service had them.

Comment: if i do that, then E2EActivityId is different for both the workflows.